# How to add icon to mat-icon-button

Tags: angular-material, angular5, angular-material2

I am using Angular with Material

```
 <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon svgIcon="thumb-up"></mat-icon>Start Recording</button>
```

I am trying to add an icon to button, but I can't figure out how to do it, and can't find documentation for this.

https://material.angular.io/components/button/api

looking the docs, there is this:

[image]

that button has the following html:

```
<a _ngcontent-c1="" aria-label="Angular Material" class="docs-button mat-button" mat-button="" routerlink="/" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" href="/"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">
    <img _ngcontent-c1="" alt="angular" class="docs-angular-logo" src="../../../assets/img/homepage/angular-white-transparent.svg">
    <span _ngcontent-c1="">Material</span>
  </span> <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay">
</div>
</a>
```

is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Just add the `<mat-icon>` inside `mat-button` or `mat-raised-button`. See the example below. Note that I am using material icon instead of your svg for demo purpose:

```
<button mat-button>
    <mat-icon>mic</mat-icon>
    Start Recording
</button>
```

**OR**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent">
    <mat-icon>mic</mat-icon>
    Start Recording
</button>
```

Here is a link to [**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-12-k9xtek?file=app/app.component.html).

Comment: thanks, any idea how I can use an icon that is not one of the default icons? I want to use a "play" button (like a filled-in chevron), but "play" is not an available icon.

Comment: In that case you have to register and icon using mat icon registry.

Comment: Hi @Faisal I used this also and it worked, but I'm registering the icons as an SVG and using them as it follows <mat-icon svgIcon="search"></mat-icon> but when using it inside a <button> it's not rendering, do you know why?

Comment: @DannyG you will have to register your svg icons: https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview#registering-icons

Comment: can you please help me to fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925724/how-to-customize-angular-material-design-stepper-in-angular-4 @Faisal

Comment: According to what I understand of the spec, why didn't you put `mat-icon-button` instead of `mat-button`? https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview

Comment: @Pipo , `mat-icon-button` will only render a circular "icon button" with transparent background, without any text. When we have to add text + icon, then we use `mat-icon` inside a `mat-button`.

Answer (score 23):

All you need to do is add the **mat-icon-button** directive to the button element in your template. Within the button element specify your desired icon with a **mat-icon** component.

You'll need to import **MatButtonModule** and **MatIconModule** in your app module file.

From the Angular Material buttons example page, hit the view code button and you'll see several examples which use the material icons font, eg.

```
<button mat-icon-button>
  <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">favorite</mat-icon>
</button>
```

In your case, use

```
<mat-icon>thumb_up</mat-icon>
```

As per the getting started guide at https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started, you'll need to load the material icon font in your index.html.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or import it in your global styles.scss.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");
```

As it mentions, any icon font can be used with the mat-icon component.

Comment: Just FYI, this creates a circular button around the icon only. So, if you add a button-text next to the icon, it'll break.

Answer (score 20):

My preference is to utilize the `inline` attribute.  This will cause the icon to correctly scale with the size of the button.

```html
    <button mat-button>
      <mat-icon inline=true>local_movies</mat-icon>
      Movies
    </button>

    <!-- Link button -->
    <a mat-flat-button color="accent" routerLink="/create"><mat-icon inline=true>add</mat-icon> Create</a>
```

I add this to my `styles.css` to:

- solve the vertical alignment problem of the icon inside the button
- material icon fonts are always a little too small compared to button text

```css
button.mat-button .mat-icon,
a.mat-button .mat-icon,
a.mat-raised-button .mat-icon,
a.mat-flat-button .mat-icon,
a.mat-stroked-button .mat-icon {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Add to app.module.ts

> import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

& link in your global index.html.

Answer (score 1):

the above CSS can be written in SASS as follows (and it actually includes all button types, instead of just button.mat-button)

```
button,
a {
    &.mat-button,
    &.mat-raised-button,
    &.mat-flat-button,
    &.mat-stroked-button {
        .mat-icon {
            vertical-align: top;
            font-size: 1.25em;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Material icons use the Material icon font, and the font needs to be included with the page.

Here's the CDN from Google Web Fonts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```